# Can;t we pass int value to recycler view in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

i created a class for temp data to show. Obviously my app is crashing but if i change int sno to String sno then there is no problem. i want to know for int, if yes then how?

```
public class Contact
{
    public int sno;
    public String phone;
    public String name;

    Contact(int sno, String phone, String name)
    {
        this.sno = sno;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My custom adapter class file -->

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private final Contact[] localDataSet;
//    private TextView textView;
    private TextView textView2;
    private TextView textView3;

    /**
     * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using
     * (custom ViewHolder).
     */
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView textView2;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View

            textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        }

        public TextView getTextView() {
            return textView2;
        }
    }

    /**
     * step 1 Initialize the dataset of the Adapter.
     *
     */
    public CustomAdapter(Contact[] dataSet) {
        localDataSet = dataSet;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        // Create a new view, which defines the UI of the list item
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.contact_layout, viewGroup, false);
//        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView2 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position)
    {
        // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the
        // contents of the view with that element
//        textView.setText(localDataSet[position].sno);
        textView2.setText(localDataSet[position].name);
        textView3.setText(localDataSet[position].phone);
    }
```

i commented out one textview temporarily to not get sno print then my app works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an `int` as an argument with [`TextView::setText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)), then you're expected to pass a resource id. Your crash, if you see the error log, will likely say something like "could not resolve resource id for [some_number]".

Convert the `int` to a `String` before setting it to your `TextView` and you'll no longer have a problem, i.e. `textView.setText(String.valueOf(localDataSet[position].sno));`

Answer (score 0):

When you set int value to textView, app crashed. You can use it like this.

```
textView.setText(localDataSet[position].sno+"")
```